# OpenCV: Refine Cascade Face Detection

Tags: opencv, cascade, face-detection

I'm making system for emotion detection on Android mobile phone. I'm using OpenCV's Cascades (LBP's or Haars) to find face, eyes, mouth areas etc. What I have observed till now that accuracy isn't stable. There are situations where I can't find eye or I have "additional faces" in the background due to very slight change of light. What I wanted to ask is:

1) Is Haar Cascade more Accurate than LBP?
2) Is there any good method for increasing accuracy of detection? Like find face/eyes etc on binarized image, or use some edge detection filter, saturation, anything else?

Comment: HAAR is slightly more accurate, but LBP is *much* faster

Comment: If you have an idea about how big (or small) the relative feature you're looking for are - e.g. eyes are smaller than face, face will always be at least 120px wide - try restricting the sizes you're searching for to increase speed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Microsoft API for face emotion detection ..i am trying in my project so..result is best..try this link
 https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/emotion-api

Comment: Is there any free services for it ?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes HAAR or LBP will not get a good enough result for a face detection system. if you want to get more good acc. i think you can try to using [STASM](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/)

it base on opencv and using Haar to detect face and landmark. something others you can also try [YOLO Face detection](https://github.com/dannyblueliu/YOLO-version-2-Face-detection)

if you want to build your own face detection system just base on Haar or LBP and make them get a good result, maybe you will need to using the LBP to find out the face faster and train a CNN model to get the last good result, it can make your system to detect faces in realtime. as i know, the [SEETAFACE](https://github.com/seetaface/SeetaFaceEngine) is using this way to make a realtime faces detection.